# React map function error, in which spot did I make wrong?

Tags: reactjs

Dear stack overflow users.

I absolutely have no idea what I have done wrong in my code.

Could anyone help me to find where the issue come from?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```html
<ul className="movie__genres">
    {genres.map((genre, index) => {
        return (
            <li key={index} className="movie__genre">
                {genre}
            </li>
        );
    })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, find some advice here how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please don't post screenshots but copy/paste all relevant code, than you're more likely to get help. Also here it's not clear what your error or bug is, so please clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

You added genres in the propTypes, but not as props received in your movie functionnal component,as i see in your screen. Try the code below

If it doesn't work could you provide the payload of genre.

```
function Movie({id, title, year, summary, poster, genres}) {

// you will get an error if you try to render an object (i guess your genre is an object?)
if it is an object, you need to target an property from the object, otherwise, if it isn't an object you could go with your {genre}
 <li key={index} className="movie__genre">
    {genre.name}
  </li>

}
```

Comment: What's was the problem?